# Extending QGIS Plugin builder result with a Combobox fails in referencing the new object

Tags: python, qt, qgis

I have extended the UI file resulting from the Plugin builder with Qt Creator.
Just added some checkboxes and a combobox, named layercombo to the form. 
The application is named jacktest.py. It uses an intermediate file jackdialog.py (generated from the plugin builder, left unchanged).

Compiled the UI file and the resource file. Then added some code to the plugin and tested this. It's no problem to get the available layer names in a QMessagebox. But how to add these to the combobox ?
Should be simple, but no option succeeds in referencing the combobox.

Error message: AttributeError: jacktest instance has no attribute 'layercombo'.

Result from my latest try:

```
# run method that performs all the real work
def run(self):

    # create and show the dialog
    dlg = jacktestDialog()
    # show the dialog
    dlg.show()
    result = dlg.exec_()
    for layer in self.iface.legendInterface().layers():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
           QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(), "Info", layer.name())
           self.layercombo.Items.Insert(0, layer.name())
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result == 1:
        # do something useful (delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the current class (which is not your dialog) when you are setting the layercombo items

Replace:

```
self.layercombo.Items.Insert(0, layer.name())
```

with

```
dlg.ui.layercombo.Items.Insert(0, layer.name())
```

but you code still won't work correctly as `exec_()` is blocking and waits until it returns so you are adding items to an invisible dialog.

Try this instead:

```
# create and show the dialog
dlg = jacktestDialog()
# show the dialog
for layer in self.iface.legendInterface().layers():
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
       QMessageBox.information( self.iface.mainWindow(), "Info", layer.name())
       dlg.ui.layercombo.Items.Insert(0, layer.name())
result = dlg.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanx Nathan, costed me a lot of time looking for this. Didn't get the link to the ui-object as a crucial part to reference. One small addition after testing your answer: my Insert code is not correct. But the more simple version works: 

dlg.ui.layercombo.addItem(layer.name()) 

Jack Schoenmakers –

Answer (score 0):

Went on in developing a Signal within the run module (code: def run (self):)

QObject.connect(dlg.ui.layercombo,SIGNAL('currentIndexChanged (int)'),self.select_one)

and the code of select_one is:

```
def select_one(self):
    comboindex = dlg.ui.layercombo.currentIndex()
    QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(), "Info", comboindex)
```

Error message:

comboindex = dlg.ui.layercombo.currentIndex()
NameError: global name 'dlg' is not defined

Suppose I have to reference dlg as a parameter in the function call, but this is not working until now.